Auth0 Nextjs to Protected Api
I have set up nextjs with auth0. I want to protect an api and use the access token for connecting to auth0 in clientside and serverside api calls.
I want api routes such as Examples/Me
Where in the api i will be able to get the auth0 id from the token.
Is this possible? I can only find documentation on client credentials flow / machine to machine....
How can i specify the audience in my nextjs app?
Alternatively can anyone reccomend an alternative solution? Other than azure b2c... im sick of that!

Figured it out...
Needed to amend this file
app/api/auth/[auth0]/route.ts
export const GET = handleAuth({
  login: handleLogin({
    authorizationParams: {
      audience: "https://audience", 
      scope: "openid profile email offline_access",
    },
  }),
});

